# Select value from data frame in period

Tags: r, join

I have the following problem - there are two data frames:

1. observations: 100 observations (= individuals) with a specific "observation date" - this date ist the baseline. There are further time points after 6 months (and maybe after 12 months).
2. visits: obervations (individuals) visit a place several times during a period of 12 months, f.e. observation 1 has 24 visits, observation 2 has 32 visits etc. During every visit data are collected - among others the "important value" (numeric). These values are connected to a visit date in the same row. So the "important value" occurs several times for each observation (f.e. 24 times for observation 1, 32 times for observation 2, etc.)

Now I would like to read the "important value" from data frame **visits** which fits best to **approximately** 6 months (+/- 15 days) after observation date and **put this value in a new column in the observations data frame**. The reason is because I want to know what was the **important value** after 6 months for each observation out of multiple visits from these many visits. The +/- 15 days idea is because the important value is not collected **exactly** after 6 months - this could be a little bit earlier or later.

I created a dummy dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

set.seed(123)

observations <- data.frame(observation_id = seq(1, 100, 1),
                           observation_date = sample(seq(as.Date('1980/01/01'), as.Date('2010/12/31'), by="day"), 100),
                           age = round(runif(100, min = 1, max = 80)), 
                           bmi = round(runif(100, min = 19, max = 30)), 
                           amount = round(runif(100, min = 10, max = 10000)), 
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

observations$observation_date_6months_later <- observations$observation_date + days(180)
observations$observation_date_6months_later_start <- observations$observation_date_6months_later + days(-10)
observations$observation_date_6months_later_end <- observations$observation_date_6months_later + days(+10)

visit_data <- data.frame(visit_observation_id = round(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 100)),
                         visit_id = seq(1, 10000, 1),
                         visit_date = sample(seq(as.Date('1980/01/01'), as.Date('2020/12/31'), by="day"), 10000),
                         important_value = round(runif(10000, min = 0.01, max = 50), 2), 
                         var2 = round(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 1000)), 
                         var3 = round(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 9000)), 
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

observations$observation_date_6months_later_important_value <- NA # I would like to read the best fitting value from data frame "visit_data"

data_joined <-
  dplyr::inner_join(visit_data, observations, by = c('visit_observation_id' = 'observation_id')) %>%
  arrange(visit_date)
```

I would be glad if someone could help me with this problem!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Just needed a couple more `dplyr` functions.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)

observations <- data.frame(observation_id = seq(1, 100, 1),
                           observation_date = sample(seq(as.Date('1980/01/01'), as.Date('2010/12/31'), by="day"), 100),
                           age = round(runif(100, min = 1, max = 80)),
                           bmi = round(runif(100, min = 19, max = 30)),
                           amount = round(runif(100, min = 10, max = 10000)),
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

observations$observation_date_6months_later <- observations$observation_date + days(180)
observations$observation_date_6months_later_start <- observations$observation_date_6months_later + days(-10)
observations$observation_date_6months_later_end <- observations$observation_date_6months_later + days(+10)

visit_data <- data.frame(visit_observation_id = round(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 100)),
                         visit_id = seq(1, 10000, 1),
                         visit_date = sample(seq(as.Date('1980/01/01'), as.Date('2020/12/31'), by="day"), 10000),
                         important_value = round(runif(10000, min = 0.01, max = 50), 2),
                         var2 = round(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 1000)),
                         var3 = round(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 9000)),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Used full_join because it keeps all the columns from both data sets.
data_joined <- full_join(observations, visit_data, 
by=c("observation_id"="visit_observation_id")) %>% 
arrange(observation_id, observation_date)

# group_by works for each ID. filter does the important 
# bit for your purpose. rowwise is necessary,
# otherwise there is an error.
success <- data_joined %>% group_by(observation_id) %>% rowwise() %>% 
filter(between(visit_date, observation_date_6months_later_start, observation_date_6months_later_end)) %>% 
select(observation_date, observation_date, visit_date, observation_date_6months_later, important_value)

success
# A tibble: 9 × 5
# Rowwise:  observation_id
  observation_id observation_date visit_date observation_date_6months_…¹ impor…²
           <dbl> <date>           <date>     <date>                        <dbl>
1             14 2005-01-13       2005-07-02 2005-07-12                    35.4 
2             20 2006-05-25       2006-11-21 2006-11-21                    49.6 
3             44 2004-01-14       2004-07-19 2004-07-12                     3.07
4             49 1987-12-16       1988-06-12 1988-06-13                    24.6 
5             58 2010-01-29       2010-07-26 2010-07-28                     6.11
6             65 1996-10-11       1997-04-17 1997-04-09                    48.1 
7             68 1985-10-17       1986-04-20 1986-04-15                    47.3 
8             72 1994-11-10       1995-05-05 1995-05-09                     3.05
9             86 1990-05-10       1990-11-13 1990-11-06                     2.03
# … with abbreviated variable names ¹observation_date_6months_later,
#   ²important_value
```

The data that you created ended up not providing many `visit_date`s that fell within the windows, so there are only a few that are successfully captured. For example, observation 1 has a six month window of 1987-03-17 to 1987-04-06 and the closest date in `visit_data` is 1987-01-21. I understand that the data were generated for this post with `sample`, just explaining why there is a low number of returned values.